# Dropdown menu in Joomla

Tags: drop-down-menu, joomla, joomla2.5

Iam have some problems with a drop down menu. I have asigned a drop down menu to the menu item "test 1". But when iam on the default page it wont show the drop down menu, when i hover the item. It only works when click on the menu item "test 1".

I need the dropdown menu to be showed, no matter witch page you are watching. 
Can some one help me? I guess it is a simple styling, but cant seem to figure it out.

You can see the website [here](http://test2.helbografisk.dk)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What module are you using for the menu system?

You may try using a different menu extension that the one being used currently.
It may be a CSS issue.

Comment: Iam using the menu module in my tempalte.

Comment: Okay, found the problem, Show Sub-menu Items was set to no. But your anwser kind of helped me.
Thanks!